# How to simplify an expression with square roots?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

The expression $\sqrt{L^2 M+\sqrt{L^2 (-J^2 + L^2 M^2)}}/\sqrt{2}$，can be simplified into $\sqrt{L}(\sqrt{LM + J}+\sqrt{LM - J})/2$, but how can I obtain this result with *Mathematica*?

That is, how can I simplify

```
Sqrt[L^2 M + Sqrt[L^2 (-J^2 + L^2 M^2)]]/Sqrt[2]
```

into

```
Sqrt[L]/2 (Sqrt[L M + J] + Sqrt[L M - J])
```

Comment: Have You tried `Simplify`?

Comment: Please correct your expressions clarify the layout. Note: `LM` is *not* equivalent to `L M`.

Comment: sometimes the best you can do is get mathematica verify that your expression is the same, have you done that? Show that code...

Comment: `Equal[{Sqrt[L^2 M + Sqrt[L^2 (-J^2 + L^2 M^2)]]/Sqrt[2], 
  Sqrt[L]/2 (Sqrt[L M + J] + Sqrt[L M - J])}]` returns true, but I'm not sure what are we trying to achieve - to verify the statement or to get _Mathematica_ to return the simplified form?

Comment: @WojciechSitkiewicz that is incorrect syntax for equal. The expressions are in fact only equal under certain conditions (eq J=1,M=1,L=-1) they are not equal.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that the first expression can be simplified to the second?

```
o1 = Sqrt[L^2 M + Sqrt[L^2 (-J^2 + L^2 M^2)]]/Sqrt[2];
o2 = Sqrt[L]/2 (Sqrt[L M + J] + Sqrt[L M - J]);
```

and

```
ru = {L -> 5, M -> 2, J -> 3.};
```

Then just

```
o1 /. ru
o2 /. ru
```

Comment: Sorry, it is " plus " in the first equation.

Comment: Given that the equation was incorrect I suggest you delete your answer, as it actually doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

By squaring both expressions and making some assumptions we can show them equal..

```
     Simplify[
            (Sqrt[L^2 M + Sqrt[L^2 (-J^2 + L^2 M^2)]]/Sqrt[2] )^2 
              ==
            ( Sqrt[L]/2 (Sqrt[L M + J] + Sqrt[L M - J]))^2  , 
       Assumptions -> { L > 0, M > Abs[J/L]}] 

     (* True *)
```

As near as I can tell under those assumptions this equality should still hold without squaring the expressions, but Simplify fails to see that for some reason.